# Web routes defined in route list but not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a route. I'm trying to use named routes.

```
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home1', function(){
    return 'test';
}]);
```

It's not running. Any idea why this could be. It is not grouped with any other routes.
[image]

Comment: Any error message(s)...?

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Do the other pages work? How are you calling your route? How are you running your app, artisan serve?

Comment: Yes, other pages work. I'm running through mamp

Comment: did you try setting `/home` with a slash?

Comment: Can you add your entire routes file? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('home', function(){
    return 'test';
});
```

If you intend to use named routes, do this:

```
Route::get('home', function(){
    return 'test';
})->name('home1');
```

If you intend to use the 'as' syntax, do it this way:

```
Route::get('/home', [
    'uses' => 'ControllerName@functionName',
    'as' => 'routeName'
]);
```

Then in your 'a' tag, link to your named route like so:
`{{ route('home1')  }}`

Comment: I want a named route

Comment: I have tried that previously and it didn't work. I have added a route list screenshot

Comment: Can you show me the anchor tag where you are calling the 'home' route?